# What is the difference between -keep and -keepclassmembers in ProGuard?

Tags: android, proguard

I read through http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html but cannot get their differences.

I tested with 2 different options and decompiled the outcome. Both seems to produce the same result.

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    *;
}
```

---

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    *;
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The first (`-keep`) will keep **classes and class members** that implement `android.os.Parcelable` **from being removed or renamed.**

The latter (`-keepclassmembers`) will keep **class members only** of classes that implement `android.os.Parcelable` **from being removed or renamed.**

Comment: Can you please clarify "from been removed or renamed"?

Comment: Shrinking and Obfuscating are among Proguard's Core functions. **Shrinking (Remove)** and **Obfuscating (Rename)**.